# find date and time in string and reformat removing spaces using sed in windows or cmd

Tags: regex, windows, datetime, sed, spaces

I cannot figure out a good sed, regex, or windows cmd, or both, way to reformat lines in a csv file with a horrible datetime implementation to something usable:

Given:

```
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,7/8/13   0:00,55.10

Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,7/8/13   0:10,55.50
```

I need to "find" the date time part, e.g. (7/8/13   0:00) and reformat into a SQL-like DATETIME:

```
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,2013-07-08 00:00:00,55.10

Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,2013-07-08 00:10:00,55.50
```

As you can see this may require adding '0' in front of months, days, and the hours, and then :00 for seconds.

Getting the datetime area is something like:

```
sed -E 's#^([^/]+)/([^/]+)/([0-9]+)
```

, but I am not able to "get to it" first...need to find that second ',' first?

There will always be the 4 fields per line:

```
Name,SomeEquipmentId,DateTime,Value.
```

Is there a good combination of sed + windows cmds to get this? Or am I better off writing higher-level code to do this all?

UPDATE with awk:
I tried a few commands such as:
awk -F , "{split($3,a,[:blank:]); vdate=a[1]; tdate=a[2]; print vdate}" file.csv

but it gives a syntax error on the [ char. Escaping it doesnt work. I tried \""%%3s, but that returns the entire string still (e.g. 7/18/13   00:10).
Is there a better awk string command to use instead of trying to break them into an array?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way with `GNU awk`

```
awk '
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  split($3,ary,/[\/: ]/)
  $3=mktime(20 ary[3]" "ary[1]" "ary[2]" "ary[6]" "ary[7]" "00)
  $3=strftime("%F %T",$3)
}1' csvfile
```

#### Test:

```
$ cat csvfile 
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,7/8/13   0:00,55.10
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,7/8/13   0:10,55.50
```

```
$ awk '
BEGIN {
  FS=OFS=","
}
{
  split($3,ary,/[\/: ]/)
  $3=mktime(20 ary[3]" "ary[1]" "ary[2]" "ary[6]" "ary[7]" "00)
  $3=strftime("%F %T",$3)
}1' csvfile
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,2013-07-08 00:00:00,55.10
Name,Equip1_SA-TEMP -- ASample,2013-07-08 00:10:00,55.50
```

Comment: Perfect! I put this in a file since windows cmd wont accept single quotes.

Comment: I need to retract my acceptance, this fails when time has 2 digits in hour, e.g. "7/8/13  10:00". There are only 2 spaces between the 13 and 10, but when single hours are present, its 3 spaces. awk throws a fatal error when it reaches a time with double hour digits. I will see if I can update your script to make it work.

Comment: Just needed to add a conditional on size of the split, had one less element if the hour was double-digit.

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look at gawk versus sed.  gawk is a cyclic text processor that makes it fairly easy to deal with fields within a record.  In your examples it looks like the timestamp is always the third of four fields. So the awk script on a linux system would look something like:

```
awk 'BEGIN {FS=","} {print $1 "," $2 "," MODIFIED_$3 "," $4}' < datafile
```

where `MODIFIED_$3` is the timestamp reformatted using awk's built in time [functions](http://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/gawk.html#Time-Functions).

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I started trying awk, but in windows cmd it is giving me a headache! I cannot parse $3 using " " (e.g. \"" \""), I tried [:space:] and [:blank:] but cmd gives errors on those. I will update my question with what i have so far.

Comment: @KJackson: Put the code in a file and forget that weird handling of quotes. And run it with `-f` switch: `awk -f script.awk datafile`

Comment: Thanks for file suggestion, that helped get commands through. JS's answer worked perfect, so accepting that.